# It's possible to get a "friendly" URL using a SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I have a site (which is not my magento site) where I connect to magento's DB and use some SQL queries to show recent products. I know I should use the API, but is not the case now.

I just append `"http://www.domain.com/catalog/product/view/id/"` to the product ids.

It works fine, I just want to know if it's possible to get the same friendly urls for each product I get in the shop, like `http://www.domain.com/dvd/movies/matrix-3.html`

How can I do this?

Comment: Marcelo,it is possiable ,i will give u solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcelo,magento have save product seo url in catalog product table and core_rewrite_url

Here the query

```
Select product_id, request_path from  core_url_rewrite 
where store_id=$storeId and product_id =$ProductID and is_system=1
```

Here core_url_rewrite table  is provide all urls  of a  product.
gives

```
http://www.domain.com/dvd/movies/matrix-3.html
http://www.domain.com/dvd/matrix-3.html
```

if product is include to a category then run below query

```
    Select product_id, request_path from  core_url_rewrite 
    where store_id=$storeId and product_id =$ProductID  and is_system=1  
   and category_id=$categoryId
```

The query give `http://www.domain.com/dvd/movies/matrix-3.html`